# SignificantLocationChanges with SceneDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, appdelegate, uiscenedelegate

I am working with significantLocationChanges and in killed state when there is a significant location change then it wakes up the app but launchOptions is always nil I heard that if you are using SceneDelegate then launchOptions in AppDelegate will always be nil so I tried this in SceneDelegate it also wakes up the app with empty connectionOptions. How can I get UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.location?